# Looping through a data source in SoapUI

Tags: testing, soapui

I am using SoapUI pro and I have a test case with 70 test steps.
I have an excel sheet with 70 rows which is used as the data source.
My scenario is that, the values in each row should be assigned to each test step.
Eg: test step 1 should retreive the value from row 1......test step 70 should retreive the value from row 70.
The problem I am facing is that after I insert a data source loop to cycle through the data source, all the test steps take the final row values.
I configured the data source loop with target step as first test step.
Is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: What you describe is not a loop, it is a single pass: one step to one row. So a data source (a loop step) will not work. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @SiKing Thank you for the reply. I guess you are right. So is there a way I can assign each row to a test step?

Comment: You could have a look at http://smartbear.com/product/ready-api/soapui-ng/features/data-driven-tests/ and http://readyapi.smartbear.com/soapui/data_driven/start for how you could loop over all the rows in your Excel file.

Comment: This is starting get really broad and out of hand! I would probably set up a datasource loop anyway, inside the loop have only a script step that populates each of the 70 test steps. Once the loop exists, just run the test steps.